# assigning pointers?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a queue data structure.

```
Queue()
```

does the following create any memory leaks:

```
Queue* test = new Queue();
Queue* test1 = test;
delete test1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you'd be left with 2 dangling pointers - `test` and `test1`. You can no longer use them until they point to something meaningful.

Comment: Indeed, but when the two dangling pointers go out of scope, I won't leaking any memory?

Comment: @marcwho no, because you `delete` the allocated memory.

Comment: @marcwho when they go out of scope you'll not have dangling pointers, you will have a memory leak(if you don't `delete` them)

Comment: @marcwho no, you won't have a memory leak, because you do delete the memory.